# Unable to initialize php-fpm

Tags: php

I have facing some problem in php-fpm using ngnix.but when I access a server it throws a 502 Bad Gateway.

**Error logs : -**

```
11-Aug-2014 07:27:02] ERROR: epoll: unable to initialize
[11-Aug-2014 07:27:02] ERROR: epoll: unable to initialize
[11-Aug-2014 07:27:02] ERROR: Unable to initialize the event module epoll
[11-Aug-2014 07:27:02] ERROR: Unable to initialize the event module epoll
[11-Aug-2014 07:27:02] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[11-Aug-2014 07:27:02] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

Comment: There should be some log entries before that, please post them too.

Answer (score 0):

PHP-FPM can use a variety of mechanisms for listening on the potentially large number of sockets it has to maintain. By default it choses the mechanism automatically, but it can be overridden by using the `events.mechanism` configuration setting in php-fpm.conf.

From the upstream configuration file:

```
; Specify the event mechanism FPM will use. The following is available:
; - select     (any POSIX os)
; - poll       (any POSIX os)
; - epoll      (linux >= 2.5.44)
; - kqueue     (FreeBSD >= 4.1, OpenBSD >= 2.9, NetBSD >= 2.0)
; - /dev/poll  (Solaris >= 7)
; - port       (Solaris >= 10)
; Default Value: not set (auto detection)
; events.mechanism = epoll
```

In other words, if epoll doesn't work for whatever reason (e.g. some virtualization restriction, etc), you can pick another mechanism.

Comment: sorry I could not get what your saying .

Comment: error log  :       12-Aug-2014 07:09:01] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[12-Aug-2014 07:09:05] WARNING: [pool www] child 21368 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 4.377809 seconds from start
[12-Aug-2014 07:09:05] NOTICE: [pool www] child 21404 started
[12-Aug-2014 07:10:19] WARNING: [pool www] child 21680 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 44.613075 seconds from start
[12-Aug-2014 07:10:19] NOTICE: [pool www] child 21740 started

Comment: There is probably a problem with your PHP-FPM installation on your system. You can try to change the events.mechanism setting, but ultimately you will have to check if you installed PHP correctly. This could be caused for example by using PHP packages not designed for the system you are running.